# What are the differences between the formats "matroska", "matroska,webm" and "webm" in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've run into these very similarly named formats while using ffmpeg:

1. `matroska`
2. `matroska,webm`
3. `webm`

What are the differences between 1. and 2.? And what about 2. and 3.? Can video players that support the `webm` or `matroska` formats also generally play files that have the `matroska,webm` format if the video and audio codecs are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebM is a subset of Matroska, so there's one module (demuxer / muxer) that handles their reading & writing respectively. The middle name `matroska,webm` is the name of the ffmpeg demuxer that reads both Matroska and WebM files. It is specific to ffmpeg and does not represent any variant or unique format.

Comment: How would I find out whether a file specified as having the format `matroska,webm` is actually using the `matroska` format or the `webm` format then? From my experience of using `ffprobe` for mkv files, they're always reported as having the format `matroska,webm`. Should I expect these files to have the `matroska` format by default?

Comment: WebMs accept video with codecs VP8, VP9 or AV1 only; for audio, codecs Opus or Vorbis only. There is a 'doctype'  written in the first few dozen bytes. You can check using a hex editor.

Comment: So just to confirm: is there no way to be sure of the format used by using only `ffmpeg` or `ffprobe` if the format given by ffprobe is `matroska,webm` - do I need to use another tool to be 100% sure? My intended use for this is to check whether or not a file can be played by a certain browser; firefox for example doesn't support the Matroska container but does support WebM. I'm using `ffmpeg` to automatically do this check and would prefer not having to use another tool on top of `ffmpeg`.